# Why is GDB "thread apply all where" not sending all output to a file (only some...)?

Tags: c, gdb

I'm using the following GDB function:

```
define why                 
set pagination on          
set logging file ~/why.dump
set logging overwrite      
set logging on             
set logging redirect off   
thread apply all where     
set logging off            
set pagination on          
end
```

When I run the function why, I see in my terminal the normal backtrace. Something like:

```
Thread 78 (Thread 3123):                          
#0  0xffffe424 in blah ()                         
#1  0xb63330d4 in blah () at blah                 
#2  0xadfe74f9 in blah () from blah               
#3  0xadf724d2 in blah () from blah               
#4  0xadf6aadb in blah () from blah               
#5  0xadf6d806 in blah () from blah               
#6  0xadffa717 in blah () from blah               
#7  0xae3f0f20 in blah ()                         

#9  0xadff83f1 in blah () from blah               
#10 0xadf942af in blah () from blah               
#11 0xadf946d8 in blah () from blah               
#12 0xadf9afac in blah () from blah               
#13 0xadfe57b1 in blah () from blah               
#14 0xb632eb98 in blah (arg=0xab981b70) at blah   
#15 0xb62ad70e in blah () at blah
```

But my ~/why.dump skips the actual backtrace under each thread and just looks like:

```
warning: Current output protocol does not support redirection

Thread 5 (Thread 2886):

Thread 4 (Thread 2885):

Thread 2 (Thread 2884):

Thread 1 (Thread 2883):
```

I'm trying to get the output for each thread bt to show in my log as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The warning in the output is interesting.  It comes from `execute_command_to_string`, which is used from Python, not the main part of gdb.  That is suggestive but I didn't look too deeply.  In any case I think this is just a bug and I'd recommend reporting it.

Also I noticed that your script starts with `set pagination on`, which seems like the opposite of what you'd want.